# Awk + printf: substitute long values by "#######"

Tags: bash, awk, printf

I get some data from a query in mysql that I need to convert to a nice looking table.
Then I use awk and printf to align columns, format numbers, etc.

```
cat /home/jm/mysql/pruebas/pruebat.txt | awk 'BEGIN { FS = ";" } ; {printf "%-'$A's %-'$B's %'\'''$C'd %'\'''$D'd %'\'''$E'd %'\'''$F'.2f %'\'''$F'.2f %'\'''$F'.2f\n", $1, $2, $3, $4, $5, $6, $7, $8 }' >> /home/jm/mysql/pruebas/prn.tx
```

My problem appears when some fields are too long (say, the % variation between too years is -12.345,67%). I would prefer to show just ###### in that case.
If I use a case/when/then/end in my query, I can substitute the long value by the string ######, but as awk+printf reads this field as a decimal number, it shows 0.00% instead of the desired ######.
Is there any way to write "if this variable is too long, just print ######"?
Thanks,

jm

EDIT:

My source file (forget about headers):

```
S_V;NO INVENTARIABLES;-41.7000;-67.5200;-25.8200;61.91846523;100.00000000;100.00000000
S_A;ARTICULOS PROMOCIONES;54.4400;631.3200;576.8800;1059.66201323;-1412.30712711;-19.76018501
S_B;PRODUCTOS TECNICOS;975.6000;1951.2000;975.6000;100.00000000;36.01476015;34.61254613
S_S;MATERIAL ELECTRICO;2237.6600;5103.2500;2865.5900;128.06190395;40.21030898;43.42859942
```

My output:

```
fam     nombre                               2011       2012        var        %   %mgn11   %mgn12
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
S_V     NO INVENTARIABLES                     -41        -67        -25    61.92   100.00   100.00
S_A     ARTICULOS PROMOCIONES                  54        631        576 1,059.66 -1,412.31   -19.76
S_B     PRODUCTOS TECNICOS                    975      1,951        975   100.00    36.01    34.61
S_S     MATERIAL ELECTRICO                  2,237      5,103      2,865   128.06    40.21    43.43
```

My wish (or similar):

```
fam     nombre                               2011       2012        var        %   %mgn11   %mgn12
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
S_V     NO INVENTARIABLES                     -41        -67        -25    61.92   100.00   100.00
S_A     ARTICULOS PROMOCIONES                  54        631        576   ######   ######   -19.76
S_B     PRODUCTOS TECNICOS                    975      1,951        975   100.00    36.01    34.61
S_S     MATERIAL ELECTRICO                  2,237      5,103      2,865   128.06    40.21    43.43
```

Comment: please, post an input, and the output example of what you will to have; andalso, try to rephrase your question -- mainly your code --, it's hard even to indent

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's start by rewriting your script in reasonable shell+awk syntax, best I can tell:

```
awk -F\; -v fmt="%-${A}s %-${B}s %'${C}d %'${D}d %'${E}d %'${F}.2f %'${F}.2f %'${F}.2f\n" '
{ printf fmt, $1, $2, $3, $4, $5, $6, $7, $8 }
' /home/jm/mysql/pruebas/pruebat.txt >> /home/jm/mysql/pruebas/prn.tx
```

Now, the problem you have is that your format string is specifically saying to print a number when in fact you want to print a string, so use sprintf to create your numbers and then if you're not happy with the result change it to a string for output. Something like this (untested):

```
awk -F\; -v fmt="%-${A}s %-${B}s %'${C}d %'${D}d %'${E}d %'${F}.2f %'${F}.2f %'${F}.2f\n" '
BEGIN{ split(fmt,fmtA,/ /) }
{
    for (i=1;i<=NF;i++) {
       $i = sprintf(fmtA[i],$i)
       if (gsub(/[^[:space:]]/,"&",$i) > 6) {
           $i = "######"
       }
    }
    print
}
' /home/jm/mysql/pruebas/pruebat.txt >> /home/jm/mysql/pruebas/prn.tx
```

Comment: Thanks Ed. My debug: awk: cmd. line:5: (FILENAME=/home/jm/mysql/pruebas/pruebatt.txt FNR=1) fatal: not enough arguments to satisfy format string
        `%-7s %-30s %'10d %'10d %'10d %'8.2f %'8.2f %'8.2f
'
                 ^ ran out for this one

Comment: The split() failed due to you using the non-default FS. I've updated the script now.

Comment: I also see from your posted expected output that you just want to count non-spaces in the length consideration so I've updated my script to reflect that. I actually think this is the wrong approach though - it'd be better to get your numbers as you want them and THEN pad with spaces afterwards but since the formatting info is hidden in your $A, etc. I can't tell how it really needs to be coded. Do you really need the formatting info to be in the shell variables or could you just do it in awk?

Comment: Letters A to F just pretend to set the length of every field (7,30,10,10,10,8 actually). The reason for doing that is avoiding setting it in the first awk I run for the header (because the format of the fields is different, text instead of numbers) and the second awk I run for the footer (not shown in the attached script for beeing redundant). As you see, text (s), number(d) anf float(f) format is already written in the awk sentence. Thanks.

Comment: Back again: As you may supose, your script works great, but, for those columns with a fixed lenght over 6 digits, it is unneeded (and undesired) to convert them to "#######". For instead, the second column is actually 30 digits long, so it shouldn't be converted. Perhaps "we" didn't take the right way...;)

Comment: Decided to go for a KISS solution, using the source query: if value > 999.99 then print 999.99. It doesn't matter if I get 999.99 instead of ###### if everybody understands that the real value is higher (or lower, for negatives). Thanks.